# .aspx C# Menu Security with Dynamic Menu

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, menu, frameworks

A little background: I'm try to rewrite my company's intranet site that has documents and applications that I'm dynamically pulling from SQL. There are two tables that the old intranet uses to dynamically generate the menu and allows users to opens the link based on if they have permission using MenuSecurity. The old webpages where made with Visual Basic and .aspx.

I'm needing to rewrite this with .aspx and C# .Net Framework, (which I'm new to both and trying to learn with this project).

```
[Menu]
ID(int) 
ParentID(int)
MenuName(varchar(50))
URL(varchar(500))
Secure(nchar(1))
```

I use this [code](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/190355/N-Level-MultiLevel-Bootstrap-Responsive-ASPNet-Menu-control-for-Mobile-Phone-Tablet-and-Desktop-display/) to dynamically call the multilevel nav menu. I'm getting the user info from using this piece of code:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

What I'm needing to do is populate the menu based on who is currently logged in and what they have access to.

```
[MenuSecurity]
ID(int)
UserID(int)
UserName(varchar(50))
MenuID(int)
MenuText(varchar(50))
Hidden(nchar(1))
```

I will appreciate any help or direction on getting this accomplished.

Comment: Since that code you referred to uses SQL, could you not just create SQL statement with `WHERE` clause on `MenuSecurity` table?

Comment: penleychan you got me in the right direction and I got the query I needed to get this accomplished. Thank you.